# Java, Webservices: do I need Tomcat/GlassFish or any other server to run a simple "web service"

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, glassfish

I've been looking at few tutorial on how to create a webservice and most of them were using in the "web service" side GlassFish or TomCat, I was wondering if they are essential since I would like to run a small "web Service" in the backbround of my remote server, the server os is Windows Server.

Thanks Luther.

Comment: No they are not. You can always write your own.

Answer (score 3):

As the name suggest, web service is a services exposed and available on web interface. Tomcat/Glassfish are web containers or web servers to hosts such services. You don't need containers to write the services code but you need them to deploy you web services.

Comment: Related just to web services, from what I understand, I need web container for XML/WSDL, or are there any other main reasons?

Comment: @Luther Web containers are basically to host web applications. Web containers accept the incoming HTTP request, looks for the URL and context and identifies an application , which can cater the request. Then your application gets the request and your web service methods are called, from where you send back the response.

Answer (score 1):

Juned Ahsan is right. I would suggest to use Tomcat for a beginning. It is faster than glassfish or if you dont want to run and configure application server on your own machine you can use Google App engine https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/soap

Comment: is Google App engine free for simple testing?

Comment: It is a very specific platform... I cannot say if it is better for you to use Tomcat or Google App Engine. Maybe it is better to use Tomcat for server side and SoapUI for simple client testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out using javax.xml.ws.Endpoint class (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html).

This allows you to try out web service without using any web/application servers.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the steps specified in http://www.cis.umassd.edu/~hxu/Projects/UMD/WebServices/

Answer (score 0):

Ya your need server to Deploy your webservices and that will used and consume by the user or Soap Client. and Tomcat/Glassfish are the Server who Deploy your application means your Webservices on the Server and you can consume it. and ya for that Glassfish is more better then tomcat.